# Taxonomies within plugin invalid

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

I have two taxonomies being registered in a functions file. They are then initialized like so:

```
function foo_register_post_types_and_taxonomies() {
  foo_register_post_types(); // defined in lib/post_types.php
  foo_register_taxonomies(); // defined in lib/taxonomies.php
}

add_action('init', 'foo_register_post_types_and_taxonomies');
```

The problem is that within a plugin i'm building, those two taxonomies are invalid. I think from what I've been reading is that the plugin runs before the taxonomies have been initialized? How do solve this so I can access these tax's from within my plugin?

In other words, outside of the plugin in any template file, when I run **get_terms('school')**, I get an array of terms for the taxonomy 'school'. Running this same code within a plugin returns invalid taxonomy. That's my problem in a nutshell.

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information. What does "within" the plugin mean? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @s_ha_dum, I added a little more to the issue. Hope this helps you understand what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: where in your plugin do you try to use `get_terms`? you need to hook it to run later than `init`, after the taxonomies are registered. everything you do in a plugin should be hooked to run on some action or filter, typically nothing should just run when the plugin file is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your taxonomies register where you've told them to register, on the `init` hook [which is the recommended hook for registering them](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy). That much you are doing correctly.

And yes, the plugins themselves will load prior to that hook's execution. You can see that by [comparing the `init` hook's location in the load sequence to the `plugins_loaded` hook's placement](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

You don't say exactly what you are trying to accomplish but the trick is that any code intended to access your taxonomies needs to run on the `init` hook (possibly with a higher than normal priority) or on a later hook.

Comment: Thanks. Wrapping my plugin in a function and adding and init hook with a later execution order solved this for me. For others looking for an answer, 

My taxonomies registered outside the plugin:
add_action('init', 'foo_register_post_types_and_taxonomies', 10);

My code that needs to use those taxonomies:
add_action('init', 'foo_plugin_code', 20);